# Faster way to copy data from Oracle to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oracle, sqlbulkcopy

I have been trying to copy data (80000 rows, 105 columns) from Oracle to SQL Server using this code:

```
OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection(ORACLE_CONNECTION_STR); 
oraCon.Open();                
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = oraCon;
cmd.CommandText = packageName;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add(PARAM_YEAR_TERM, OracleDbType.Int32);
param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param1.Value = yearTerm;        
OracleParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add(PARAM_RESULT, OracleDbType.RefCursor);
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(SQL_CONNECTION_STR);
sqlCon.Open();               
SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon);
bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
bulk.BatchSize = 5000;                
bulk.DestinationTableName = string.Format("dbo.{0}", tableName);               
bulk.WriteToServer(reader);
```

I changed various `BatchSize` and tried but it takes at least 10 minutes. Do you have any idea to make it faster?

Comment: Did you try Linked server on sql server? You could copy data directly from one database to second one.

Comment: Make your oracle stored procedure run faster

Comment: Does on the Oracle server or the SQL Server or another machine? If changing batchsize makes no difference then yes it could well be the Oracle performance. Try using SQLPLUS directly on the Oracle server to measure how long it takes to export all the data.