# SqlBulkCopy in C# for copy from Oracle view to SQL Server table too slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to use SqlBulkCopy to copy from Oracle to SQL Server, I have a view in oracle with 12 million records so I'm looking for a fast way to copy.

I've done some analysis and I would be able to not have to copy all, but just the subsets needed (around 10~15k records)  for this I assume would have to be quite fast.

I have the following methods:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        string oracleConnectionString =
            "Data Source=OracleSource ";
        string sql =
            "Select * From view Where filters In('filter1', 'filter2')";

        var dt = GetDataTable(oracleConnectionString, sql);

        InsertData(dt);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        int timeSpan = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Seconds;
        Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString() + " Seconds in total for operation");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

---

```
private static DbDataReader GetDataTable(
        string connectionString,
        string sql
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading From Oracle Started");
        var startTimeOracle = DateTime.Now;

        var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();
        var command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        Console.WriteLine("Reading From Oracle Finished");
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - startTimeOracle).Seconds + " Seconds to retrieve from oracle");

        return reader;
    }
```

---

```
private static void InsertData(DbDataReader dt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing to SqlServer Started");
        var startTimeSqlServer = DateTime.Now;
        string sql = "Truncate table table;" + Environment.NewLine;
        string connectionString = "sqlServerInfo";
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);

        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
        bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
        
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 100;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);

        Console.WriteLine("Writing to SqlServer Finished");
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - startTimeSqlServer).Seconds + " Seconds to copy into SqlServer");

    }
```

This process, for copying 14k records takes about 50 seconds.
If it worth mentioning, the oracle view returns 36 columns and the SQL Server table does not have any index created.

and I saw that the oracle view has some logic in it (some case conditions and some nvl that do a subquery, I'll try to reduce this somehow).

Is there something I could do better in this case?

If I do a select * into from openquery to the exact query via a linked server it takes 27 seconds to create a table and fill it. that's why I think it should be faster via C#.

Edit: after doing some changes this is the result:

```
Start
Reading From Oracle Started
Reading From Oracle Finished
3 Seconds to retrieve from oracle
Writing to SqlServer Started
Writing to SqlServer Finished
46 Seconds to copy into SqlServer
Finished
50 Seconds in total for operation
```

I have also changed the methods above.

Comment: Firstly, do not create a DataSet, as you only need a DataTable. Use `var returnDataTable = new DataTable();` and so on.

Comment: Secondly, using DataAdapter to populate a table is very slow on its own.

Comment: Try this code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34195729/5045688

Comment: Consider using the WriteToServer(DbDataReader) overload and SqlBulkCopyEnableStreaming = true. The actual end-to-end performance will depend on the speed the source reader can deliver data and the target instance. SqlBulkCopy can insert millions of rows per minute.

Comment: @Baldie47, the read time in the latest code is not correct. It includes only executing the query, not retrieving the results (which is done by the `WriteToServer` method). You mentioned the sql server write takes 4 seconds in testing but the timings in your question say 46 seconds. Which is it?

Comment: I meant to say 46 seconds, not 4. (I deleted since I couldn't modify)  but yes, the writing to sql server takes 46 seconds, (if you see the calls are at the start and end of the method,  taking in account it's after the WriteToServer method (that is receiving a DbDataReader)

Comment: If I remember right, you mentioned it took only 3 seconds to fill the data table so that should be the duration of the reader. So it's 15K rows in 46 seconds? I can't say way it would be so slow. You might try a filtered trace of `rpc_completed` events to capture the `insert bulk` timing on the server side.

Comment: No. The datareader fills in 3 seconds.  Then it takes 46 to write the datareader into the sql server. I can check the table in betweem and its real. The data is not there until the end

Comment: I just re read. We were saying the same. Sorry. I'll check to do the trace you mention to confirm

Comment: Why not just use a Linked Server and get SQL Server to do all the copying for you?

Comment: because of speed, I already have a linked server, and doing it that way takes longer than what this method should be

Comment: Mention all index present in Insert Table

Comment: the table insert doesn't have any index or constraint, was created just to insert the data (a select * into from the source and then truncate to have it empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your connection are never close.

I will use DataTable instead of DBDatareader in this scenario.DataReader are good for only small set of data.

```
     private static DataTable GetDataTable()
            {
     string oracleConnectionString =
                "Data Source=OracleSource ";
         using (OracaleConnection con=new OracaleConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = oracleConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
        
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * From view Where filters In('filter1', 'filter2')"; 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        
                
        
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
        
                
        
                return dt;
           }
        }
}
```

Similarly modify

```
private static void InsertData(DbDataReader dt)
    {
//blah blah
conn.close();
}

Are there many index in Insert Tablle ?Your insert may be slow because of many index.
```

If your Insert Table is `Heap` then you can use the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock` option so that it takes a bulk update lock on the SQL Server table instead of default row level lock.

Comment: I'm noticing from this that now my bottleneck is filling the DataTable, the writing into SQL Server seems to be fast when doing it from a DataTable.  I'll look into a way of maybe reading with an IDataReader and then converting it to a DataTable? I'll check if that would somehow speed it up

Comment: @Baldie47, As per my experience if conn is not Close then it give problem like  random error or slowness.Also I forgot to mention in connection string mention maxpool and minpool